# Is it possible to have a variable amount of Element types in a java generic class

Tags: java, generics

I was wondering if it is possible to have something like this:

```
public class foo<T...>
```

so you can call the class like

```
Foo<Object0>
Foo<Object0, Object1>
Foo<Object0, Object1, Object2>
```

With Object 0, 1 and 2 different types, like Integer, Float, String and so on. Is this possible, or would I have to write a class for each lenght of generic types? If this would be possible, how would I handle the different types?

Comment: Why would You need that? Or it's just curiosity?

Comment: @pivovarit For a `Tuple` type for instance, or for a `Callable` type with adjustable signature.

Comment: @pivovarit the obvious example I can think of would be generic type classes. that said no not possible, scala for example has  versions of such a class for up to 15 or so arguments. Pity yes

Comment: To solve problems that require such a type design, in Java you have to take a detour through the Reflection API (passing `Class` objects  around).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't have that. The best you can do is `public class Foo<T extends SomeClassOrInterface>`. So in your example with `Integer` and `Float` you can define `public class Foo<T extends Number>`.

You can also specify that T must implement more than one interface.

The syntax `public class Foo<T extends SomeInterface1 & SomeInterface2>` is valid, with `&` meaning `AND`.

Unfortunately the syntax `public class Foo<T extends SomeInterface1 | SomeInterface2>` with `|` meaning `OR` is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

A generic class is defined with the following format:

```
class name<T1, T2, ..., Tn> { /* ... */ }
```

You must specify the type parameters T1, T2 and Tn. 
Therefore, `class name<T...>` is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about a [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) generic parameter.

No, you can't. Largely because there would be no way of referencing the types, unless you used an array address, like `T[0]` etc, which is not supported.